# Como passar um atributo da classe filha através do construtor para a classe mãe

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, classes, construtor

Tenho 3 classes

Classe mãe: Animal

Classes filhas: Cachorro e Gato

Quero gravar o atributo nome somente quando um dos objetos forem instanciados `Gato` ou `Cachorro`.

Na classe mãe eu tenho o atributo Nome que pode ser somente leitura (`get`)

Como passar o valor (atributo `nome`) das classe filhas para a classe mãe através dos construtores das classes filhas?

Comment: Se as classes `Cachorro` e `Gato` são herdadas de `Animal` e `Animal` tem a propriedade `Nome` é só fazer `Nome = "nome";`. Para mais detalhes é necessário que você coloque seu código!

Comment: Você terá acesso a sua classe mãe através da palavra reservada `base`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hfw7t1ce%28v=vs.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 3):

Tem várias premissas erradas na pergunta. A primeira é o [uso errado do termo atributo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101). Eu sei, todo mundo ensina errado por causa da praga que é UML que usa este termo. As linguagens não usam, não faz sentido o seu uso.

A outra é que está achando que um campo que está na classe mãe não está na filha ou que o campo da filha precisa ser passado para a classe mãe como se a mãe fosse outra coisa isolada.

Também não está claro para você [o que é uma classe e o que é um objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100812/101). De fato parece que as classes são isoladas porque isso é visível no código, mas elas são apenas modelos. Quando tem o objeto é uma coisa só, os modelos não estão presentes de forma isolada, por isso não tem que passar nada de uma para outra, está tudo presente no objeto e basta usar normalmente.

Talvez falte entender melhor [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101).

Tem um [exemplo usando construtores encadeados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120089/101). Fora isto a pergunta precisaria ser mais específica.

```
using static System.Console;

public static class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var gato = new Gato("Dener");
        WriteLine(gato.Nome);            
    }
}

public abstract class Animal {
    public string Nome { get; private set; }
    public Animal(string nome) => Nome = nome;
}

public class Gato : Animal {
    public Gato(string nome) : base(nome) {}
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/VFSpzB). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8D7s7V). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/BaseConstructor.cs).

Answer (score 3):

Pelo que eu entendi de sua pergunta, você deseja ter uma propriedade `Nome` em sua classe `Animal` com o setter privado e deseja atribuir seu valor através do construtor da classe filha. Você pode utilizar a palavra chave `base` para chamar o construtor da classe "mãe".

```
public abstract class Animal

{
    public string Nome { get; private set; }

    public Animal(string nome)
    {
        Nome = nome;
    }
}

public class Gato : Animal
{
    public Gato(string nome) : base(nome)
    {

    }
}
```

**Exemplo:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var gato = new Gato("Miau");

        Console.WriteLine(gato.Nome);            
        Console.Read();
    }

}
```

[Referência](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-constructors)